# Is it possible to match box-shadow with a gradient?

Tags: css

On one box i have a drop-shadow:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

This results in a *gradient* on the right side of the box.

I want to match that particular gradient as the background of an other box, but I don't now how to simulate the gradient from the box-shadow as a regular shadow.

The closest i can come up with is

```
-moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) 50%, transparent 100%)
```

but it still doesn't match precisely.

Comment: This is more like a geometry question, rather than a CSS one :)

Comment: @Abody97 the geometry isn't the problem, more the confusing part of  blurring and transparency. It doesn't seem to be straightforward, but feel free to show me the opposite ;)

Comment: Did you have any solution for this?

Comment: @Phill, unfortunately no.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ ? :)